# Drupal 8 Detect Dev URL, then do something

Tags: symfony, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I want to build a module which does two things, detect what url the site is on, then if that's a dev url set some site config like install devel module and make sure caching is off etc.

Has anybody done this before and can point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: What is the criteria that you are going to use in order to determine if an url is a dev url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using something like [config_split](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split) and Drupal's standard `settings.php`.

You can include environment specific settings using an environment var, or the URL, or just a `if (file_exists($file)) {`, and then set which split to use in the include.